# How do I get the permissions of a user with Hikari?

Tags: python, discord

I am writing a Discord bot 100% off-script. I chose to use the Hikari library and to not use lightbulb or similar bot frameworks. How can I get the permissions a user has in a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hikari currently does not provide an abstracted method to do this. You will need to calculate the permissions yourself using a combination of the member's roles and channel permission overwrites if required.

If you have the `Member` object, you can fetch the member's roles in the guild using [Member.fetch_roles](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/guilds.html#hikari.guilds.Member.fetch_roles). This will return a sequence of all the member's roles in the guild which you can then iterate over and combine the permissions using [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

```py
roles = await member.fetch_roles()
permissions = hikari.Permissions.NONE
for role in roles:
    permissions |= role.permissions
```

Then to check if the member has the required permission (for example in this case ADMINISTRATOR):

```py
if (permissions & hikari.Permissions.ADMINISTRATOR) == hikari.Permissions.ADMINISTRATOR:
    # The member has the administrator permission
    ...
```

You can see all the available permissions [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)